# Finding the complement of the boolean expression $(w + x' + y +z')(w' + x + y + z')(w' + x' + y' + z')$

Tags: boolean

I am given the following boolean expression, and was told to simplify it using [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

$$(w + x' + y +z')(w' + x + y + z')(w' + x' + y' + z')$$

I approached this through the commonly used method of finding the dual, and then taking the complement of each literal afterwards.

$$wx'yz' + w'xyz' + w'x'y'z'$$

That's the dual of the function

$$w'xy'z + wx'y'z + wxyz$$

That's when I take the compliment of each literal.

I find it a little hard to believe this is correct, and that this is a correct application of De Morgan's Law. If anyone could verify or guide me if it's incorrect I'd greatly appreciate it.